# Why does event listener in supervisord listen only itself?

Tags: python, listener, alert, supervisord

Here is my supervisor.cfg file

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; (‘AUTO’ child log dir, default $TEMP)
directory=/home/debian/

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[program:scheduler]
command=/usr/local/bin/airflow scheduler
user=debian
autostart=true
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/debian/logs/scheduler.log
stderr_logfile=/home/debian/logs/scheduler.log

[eventlistener:mylistener]
command=/home/debian/listener.py
events=PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED,PROCESS_STATE_EXITED,PROCESS_STATE_UNKNOWN,PROCESS_STATE_FATAL,PROCESS_STATE,TICK_60
stdout_logfile=/home/debian/logs/listener.log
stderr_logfile=/home/debian/logs/listener.log
```

Here is the log of the event listener:

```
READY
RESULT 2
OK
READY
ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:210 pool:mylistener poolserial:0 eventname:PROCESS_STATE_STARTING len:70
processname:mylistener groupname:mylistener from_state:STOPPED tries:0READY
RESULT 2
OK
READY
ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:513 pool:mylistener poolserial:0 eventname:PROCESS_STATE_STARTING len:70
processname:mylistener groupname:mylistener from_state:STOPPED tries:0READY
RESULT 2
OK
READY
ver:3.0 server:supervisor serial:687 pool:mylistener poolserial:0 eventname:PROCESS_STATE_STARTING len:70
processname:mylistener groupname:mylistener from_state:STOPPED tries:0
```

The scheduler process is set the way it fails about every minute, but the event listener doesn't "see" those fails.

```
debian@8a517401c8a0:~$ sudo supervisorctl
mylistener                       RUNNING    pid 7307, uptime 1 day, 15:52:15
scheduler                        RUNNING    pid 3647, uptime 0:01:02 <-- short uptime
supervisor>
```

The listener itself is the example from supervisord documentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

def write_stdout(s):
    # only eventlistener protocol messages may be sent to stdout
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    sys.stdout.flush()

def write_stderr(s):
    sys.stderr.write(s)
    sys.stderr.flush()

def main():
    while 1:
        # transition from ACKNOWLEDGED to READY
        write_stdout('READY\n')

        # read header line and print it to stderr
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        write_stderr(line)

        # read event payload and print it to stderr
        headers = dict([ x.split(':') for x in line.split() ])
        data = sys.stdin.read(int(headers['len']))
        write_stderr(data)

        # transition from READY to ACKNOWLEDGED
        write_stdout('RESULT 2\nOK')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So what i did wrong? Why the listener log only own events?

Answer (score 1):

OK, that was my bad.

In the example code from documentation I had changed the line with

> write_stdout('RESULT 2\nOK')

for better formating of output and it broke this shit.

```
    # transition from READY to ACKNOWLEDGED
    write_stdout('RESULT 2\nOK\n') <-------- NEVER DO THIS, IT ACCEPTS ONLY CERTAIN TEXTS
```

Before you switch to ACKNOWLEDGED, you can print out enything you like... via write_stderr()

Comment: Adding a newline after 'OK' causes all future events to be ignored and it's seemingly impossible to diagnose after the fact as far as I can tell. My listener was written in bash so I needed to add -n: 
`echo -en "RESULT 2\nOK"`